# Extract mail list addresses from MailGun

Tags: mailgun

I want to extract the addresses OUT OF MailGun, into a CSV and delete the MailGun altogether.
The MailGun database is the only copy of the 951 addresses I have absolutely no access to the database in any form other than looking at the list in MailGun.

http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-mailinglists.html#mailing-lists

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to this problem in **C#** ,and it can get all members of a list(**not only 100 limited**).In addition, i use **Newtonsoft.Json**. Update: I found the 'total_count' has a maximum value 10000, **so if the members in your mailing list is more than 10000, the request will return the maximum value 10000**! In that case, this is not a great solution!

```
public void ExportMailList(string listName)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        List<MemberDetail> totalMember = new List<MemberDetail>();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
        client.Authenticator =
                new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                           "key-yourKey");
        RestRequest reqForTotal = new RestRequest();
        reqForTotal.Resource = "lists/{list}/members";
        reqForTotal.AddParameter("list", listName, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        int resultTotal= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Member>(client.Execute(reqForTotal).Content).total_count;
        int skipTimes = resultTotal / 100;
        for (int i = 0; i <= skipTimes; i++)
        {
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
            request.Resource = "lists/{list}/members";
            request.AddParameter("list", listName, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter("skip",100*i);
            totalMember.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Member>(client.Execute(request).Content).items);
        }

        //CreateCSVFromGenericList(...);
    }

public class Member
{
    public List<MemberDetail> items { get; set; }
    public int total_count { get; set; }
}

public class MemberDetail
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool subscribed { get; set; }
    public object vars { get; set; }
}
```

In the method CreateCSVFromGenericList(..), you can refer to [this blog](http://www.csharptocsharp.com/generate-csv-from-generic-list), and export the data to .csv file in any format you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using curl,php or any other programming language you can achieve this, then simply delete the mailing list through the control panel:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOURAPIKEY' -G \
https://api.mailgun.net/v2/lists/Your@MailingListName.com/members
```

Apikey and mailing list name are available from the control panel!

Comment: This downloads the addresses as json, not as csv. (It's still very useful, however.)

Comment: Also, it only seems to download the first 100 members.

Comment: It only downloads the first 100 users

Comment: Please show how to exceed the limit of 100 users. This answer is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In python :

```
def get_members():
    return requests.get(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/LIST_NAME/members",
        auth=("api", "key-YOUR_KEY"),
        data={'limit': 100, 'skip': 1380})
```

Note that limit and skip are useful to paginate through your member list.